# Nested BlockUI elements - Need independence from parent

Tags: jquery, jquery-blockui

We have implemented BlockUI (element blocking) for a large survey.. On most pages we have a fieldset to be blocked/unblocked based on yes/no answer, and then inside that fieldset paragraph tags that also need to have their own independent block/unblock based on an answer.  the problem we are having is when we unblock the fieldset it also affect s the items in the fieldset - but we don't want it to.

SO > Does anyone know how to tell BlockUI not to affect nested item's block/unblock status?

**Example** 
Answer to Question 1 unblocks fieldset, Question 2 in fieldset can be completed, question 2a in fieldset only to be unblocked is question 2 answer was 'yes'

**Question 1 - Yes/No** (If yes unblock fieldset)
< fieldset >
**Question 2 - Yes/No**  (if yes allow Question 2a, if no Block it)

**Question 2a - textarea**  "Provide more detail"

< /fieldset>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesting has been built into BlockUI.js by the developer..

Trail on Github: https://github.com/malsup/blockui/issues/40#